# modify url parameters using jQuery without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched for hours and I found a script in jquery which modify the url of current page. For example

```
?profile_id=<%=(rs_resq.Fields.Item("profile_id").Value)%>#inter
```

But, when I use it the page reloads and I loose all previous cached data in the DOM. I thought the reason behind this happening was the link attribute

```
rel="external"
```

so I took it off and then it stopped working.

```
<script>
$("#inter").live("pageshow", function onPageShow(e,data){

    alert('Page 2 - CID: ' + getParameterByName('profile_id'));
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}     
    </script>
```

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? `live()` was removed as of version 1.9. Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/live).

Comment: what is it exactly you are trying to do? there are alternative ways of doing anything. if you want the content to change without the page changing then you can use JS to do that.. JS can communicate with server and gets data, removes data from a div and puts new without refresh. you can call PHP functions using AJAX as well.

Answer (score 0):

NO, You CAN NOT!

A URL is always unique for a particular resource on internet. For example,

```
www.example.com/resource1.html
```

is always different from

```
www.example.com/resource2.html
```

As soon the url is changed in address bar the browser seeks for the resource where the URL is pointing to, not the same one or anything unknown.

Also, a hash-sign (#) denotes an anchor on the same page, so if you want to change the url to point to an anchor on the same page, like:

```
www.example.com/resource1.html#anotherColumn
```

it will just scroll the view to the referred section, not refresh the content.

There are frameworks available, like - AngularJS, KnockoutJS etc. which allows you to access dynamic contents with the same url but different **shebang** pointers - **#!**. But again, your page gets refreshed with every change in the url.

Hope that helps!